# Synchronize async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have problem with `async` methods. My code looks like this:

```
var bid = await _applicationDataService.GetSnapshotFromServerAsync(b.BidId.ToString(), b.BidVersion);

if (bid != null)
{
    if (await _bidManagerService.CheckIfBidExistsInLocalDbAsync(bid.BidId, bid.BidVersion))
    {
        await _bidManagerService.OverrideBidInLocalDbAsync(bid);
    }
    else
    {
        await _bidManagerService.SaveBidInLocalDbAsync(bid);
    }
}
```

and in the different place in the project i have:

```
await _bidContext.LoadBidByIdAsync(bidId.Value);
```

The problem is that the entity can not yet be saved locally but the method will try to load it. I have to somehow wait untill first block will finish downloading and saveing and then I have to run second block.

I cannot freeze main threat because the UI will be not responsive.

I found something like this :

1. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/11/10266923.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: This has nothing to do with `async`. If you are trying to load the data from *another* thread, you need to synchronize access. Or simply *don't* use a different thread. If your methods are really asynchronous, they won't block the UI. Are you using polling to load the new entity from another thread perhaps?

Comment: Yes you need some sort of `AsyncManualResetEvent` or `AsyncAutoResetEvent` (use the one in your first link). Wait for the event in second block and set the signal after first block is completed. You're done.

Comment: Voting to close; the easiest answer is to just `await` the first block before allowing the second block to run. Or capture the `Task`. Or `AsyncLazy<T>`. Or `SemaphoreSlim`. Need more context to determine which of these would be best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok , so I have done it by:

```
await Task.Run();
```

And in Run method I passed async () => { my methods };
The UI waits for that and it is working quite well. 
I have to my logic unfortunatelly.

The AutoResetEvent didnt work for me.